# Symfony4: Access DEV environment on production server

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

In Symfony3, when I want to browse the website in DEV environment on the "live" server, I just enter my ip address in `/web/app_dev.php` and open `http://www.example.com/app_dev.php/` in the browser.

Since in Symfony4, the environment is now set in `/.env`, how can I see the DEV environment on the production machine?

EDIT: I'm looking for a solution that works **in production**, so applying any *global* changes (like e.g. setting `APP_ENV=dev` in `/.env`) is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

You can change inside your `.env` file `APP_ENV` to dev like this:

```
APP_ENV=dev
```

If you set that variable symfony load the system into dev enviroment because inside Kernel.php there is this line that check that variable:

```
$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'] ?? 'dev', $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG'] ?? false);
```

If you want to do it without change .env file you can for example set a variable in the Apache vhost or Nginx FastCgi configuration, based on the URL you are visiting from - such as `APP_ENV=/home/user/app-name/dev.env` or on a live server: `APP_ENV=/etc/app-name.prod.env`

So in this case you have many .env file but you can use rule based on url

Answer (score 0):

At first this is a bad idea and that's why it [wasn't possible by default to access app_dev.php on production server](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/6028feeb988cd3d77796a94bdebd607bba74089b/web/app_dev.php#L15) (symfony < 4). You're giving a lot of internal information to public and especially to attackers.

From [symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/web_server_configuration.html):

> After you deploy to production, make sure that you cannot access the app_dev.php or config.php scripts (i.e. http://example.com/app_dev.php and http://example.com/config.php). If you can access these, be sure to remove the DEV section from the above configuration.

You should be able to debug most of the things from logs.

But if you really want to do it, you can just remove `public/index.php` and create `public/app.php` and `public/app_dev.php` like it was in symfony 3 and make it work with env variables. -  https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/tree/3.4/web

EDIT: To be clear: you can just remove `public/index.php`,  create `public/app.php`, `public/app_dev.php` (copies of `index.php`). And get inspiration from symfony 3 standard edition to adjust it to your needs.

EDIT2: As @Cerad mentioned it's a better idea to have `index.php` and `index_dev.php` file names (following Symfony4 decisions).

Comment: Hmmm.  Right idea but completely wrong implementation.  S3's app.php is not going to get you very far under S4.  Not even close.  Instead, copy index.php to index_dev.php and then edit accordingly.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I was trying to say with `and make it work with env variables.`. But you're right I was not so clear ... updating an answer.